# How does lichess lessons compare to chess.com's?

Tags: learning, lichess, best-practice, chess.com

Both Lichess and chess.com have lessons that I have tried out briefly. I have the perception chess.com (paid) lessons (https://www.chess.com/lessons) and even Youtube lessons are much broader and higher quality than lichess practice sets (https://lichess.org/practice). Lichess also has community studies (https://lichess.org/study) which I feel tend to be pretty basic and also not written or explained well. Is this perception objectively correct? From experience, are lichess lessons inadequate for anyone other than a beginner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot more resources are put into chess.com lectures than into lichess studies/practice.
This can be seen for example in the coverage of wrong moves and explanations for them being wrong. Chess.com pays trainers and employees to create high-quality material, but that means that you will also have to pay for them.
On the other hand, lichess studies are usually created by amateur chess players. Overall, you can hardly compare chess.com lectures and lichess studies.
I am sure that there are great community studies on lichess, but you have to find them. The quality of lichess studies only depends on the individual creator of that study. However, you can be sure that all chess.com lectures have a certain standard. Most lichess studies cover openings, whereas chess.com has many lectures on all parts of the game.

Comment: That's exactly why lichess created the staff picks: https://lichess.org/study/staff-picks . So now you know which studies are actually good.

Comment: Thanks for the list and for creating these studies! That's really cool - there they are - the good community studies.

Comment: So, OP can start with the lichess staff picks without having to spend on a chess.com membership. If OP is looking for an extensive range of topics or larger amount of lectures, he can consider chess.com later.